# Reverse proxy Issue in Docker Containers with Nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have 2 containers, one running SITE A (port 8001) and other SITE B (port 8080). What I am trying to do is a reverse proxy from nginx. In nginx conf, I have a configuration for SITE A as

```
server {
       listen 8000;
       client_max_body_size 500M;
       server_name code;

       location / {
          proxy_pass   http://code:8001; #code is my container name in dockercompose
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       }
      #Static file location
      location /static/ {
             alias   /library/static_root/;
         if ($request_filename ~* ^.*?/([^/]*?)$)
            {
             set $filename $1;
            }

         if ($filename ~* ^.*?\.(eot)|(ttf)|(woff)$)
         {
         add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
         }
             expires 30d;
      }


}
```

And my conf for SITE B is

```
server
    {
     listen 8000;
     server_name kolibri;

     location /learn/
     {
         proxy_pass http://kolibri:8080
         proxy_set_header   Host $host;
         proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
     }
  }
```

But whenever I try to access the /learn uri it directs me to SITE A and error occurs

```
nginx_1      | 192.168.5.100 - - [07/Jan/2019:05:51:22 +0000] "GET /static      /learn_module/learn_module0.10.3.css HTTP/1.1" 404 143 "http://192.168.5.232/learn/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0"
nginx_1      | 2019/01/07 05:51:22 [error] 9#9: *10 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/learn_module/learn_module-0.10.3.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.5.100, server: kolibri, request: "GET /static/learn_module/learn_module-0.10.3.js HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.5.232", referrer: "http://192.168.5.232/learn/"
nginx_1      | 192.168.5.100 - - [07/Jan/2019:05:51:22 +0000] "GET /static/learn_module/learn_module-0.10.3.js HTTP/1.1" 404 143 "http://192.168.5.232/learn/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0"
```

I have /static/ URI configured in SITE A so it might have redirected to SITE A but how can I make this call to SITE B itself. Hope this makes sense. Please help

Comment: Do you mean that some resources on /static/ are on site A and some are on site B? This doesn't make much sense to me, better add a prefix like /learn/ to the static resource on site B

Comment: @Siyu Both SITE A and B has their own /static/